# nodejs discord bot - message with words separated by emojis

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord

I'm writing my first Discord bot. I want him to read a users message, and then send the message back, with words separated by emojis. So the effect would be something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysg4f.png

So this is theoretically working - I say theoretically, because I used completely ridiculous solution just to show what I'm aiming for:

```js
if (message.substring(0, 2) == "m.") {
  var args = message.substring(2).trim().split(/ +/g);
  var cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  switch (cmd) {
    // m.clap

    case "clap":
      bot.sendMessage({
        to: channelID,
        message:
          ":clap: " + args[0] + " :clap: " + args[1] + " :clap: " + args[2],
      });
      break;
  }
}
```

So, obviously, this only works for max. three words sentences, and I need it to work for any length of the sentence.

I tried wrapping the "sendMessage" function in a for loop, iterating from 0 to args.length, but that makes the bot send each word in a separate message, obviously. And it won't let me put a for loop inside of the sendMessage function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `join()` method.

```
message: ':clap: ' + args.join(':clap: ')
```